# Android failure installation app

Tags: java, android

AndroidStudio gives me this error when I try to run my application.

```
06-22 11:40:46.190 1434-1555/system_process E/PackageInstaller: Commit of session 561093898 failed: Split lib_slice_3_apk was defined multiple times
06-22 11:40:46.191 3051-3051/? E/Pm: Failure details: Bundle[{android.content.pm.extra.STATUS=4, android.content.pm.extra.PACKAGE_NAME=imaginarycompany.solarplanets, android.content.pm.extra.SESSION_ID=561093898, android.content.pm.extra.LEGACY_STATUS=-2, android.content.pm.extra.STATUS_MESSAGE=INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split lib_slice_3_apk was defined multiple times}]
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: can you show your app gradle? Seems you are trying to make different flavours and have one repeated.

Comment: Add gradle file for module and full app.

Comment: Have you tried clean & rebuild? You can also try nuking the `.gradle` folder.